# How to get Json Data via ajax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i have trying to get json data via ajax in javascript . but i could not get the updated data from json while clicking the update button. Json data url also working correctly.

Mentioned below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"> 
    <script type="application/javascript"> 
function loadJSON() {
    var data_file = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/data.json";
    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers 
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
            alert(jsonObj.name);
            document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = jsonObj.name;
            document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = jsonObj.country;
        }
    }

    http_request.open("POST", data_file, true);
    http_request.send();
}
    </script> 

    <title>tutorialspoint.com JSON</title> 
  </head>
  <body> <h1>Cricketer Details</h1>
    <div id="Name">Sachin</div>
    <div id="Country">India</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadJSON()">Update Details </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

in my above code, i have the url of json data. but while click on the update button, i could get the json data via ajax.

i could not find it out which is wrong in my code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Above the code you say *" but i could not get the updated data from json while clicking the update button."* and below the code you say *"but while click on the update button, i could get the json data via ajax."*. What is it now? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You can't load the JSON file from `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/data.json`.  You need to copy it you own web server and point the URL there.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Lucky: It's important that you not do `var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();` outside the `try` block! That just defeats the purpose of the `try`. Just do `var http_request; try { http_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); }`.

Answer (score -1):

**If you have the liberty to include the jQuery library, you can do it using `$.ajax`.**
Use a regular web method that returns a json, and call it, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: serverpath + "/Service.asmx/GetJSON",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
            data = data.d;
        }
        var jsonObj = data; // or $.parseJSON(data); if required
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is not standard in any browser that I know. It's part of the jQuery library.

Comment: @FelixKling: All you need is the jQuery library. Why not?

Comment: he isn't asking for jquery

Comment: Don't you think that piece of information is crucial? And yeah, if no library is used, you should not use any.

Comment: @FelixKling: You jumped me; i'm bettering the answer in steps.

Comment: @FelixKling: Would you like to undo the downvote on the answer, the way it stands now? ;)

Comment: If you add a solution that doesn't use a library, then yes.